# Cocatenate 2 variables to put inside json is not working

Tags: json, bash, api, curl, cloudflare

I need to concatenate 2 variables, but when i execute the bash code i get this error `filters.api.malformed_request_body`.

I need to get the current IPs, to be able to add a new IP to the filter, that's because i need to use two variables, `$a` is the current IP that is in my firewall rule, and `$b` is the new IP that i will add.

From [Cloudflare](https://developers.cloudflare.com/firewall/api/cf-firewall-rules/put/)

> To preserve existing values, issue a GET request and based on the response, determine which fields (and respective values) to include in your PUT request and that way, avoid any undesired overwrites.

Code:

```
a=122.16.89.10
b=137.77.77.77

curl -X PUT \
     -H "X-Auth-Email: EMAIL" \
     -H "X-Auth-Key: KEY" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -d '[
{
   "id": "ID",
   "paused": false,
   "expression": "(ip.src in {'$a'" "'$b'})",
   "description": "Block IP"
}
]' "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/ZONE/filters"
```

I also tried: `"(ip.src in {'$a $b'})"` and:

```
new_filter="$a $b"
...
...
"(ip.src in {'$new_filter'})"
```

If i `echo $new_filter` it shows the correct result:

```
new_filter="$a $b"
echo $new_filter
#122.16.89.10 137.77.77.77
```

When i use the variable `$new_filter` it also show this error `curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 13` line 13 is this one `-H "Content-Type: application/json" \`.

None worked, why? I get this error:

```
{                                                                   
  "result": null,                                                   
  "success": false,                                                 
  "errors": [                                                       
    {                                                               
      "code": 10014,                                                
      "message": "filters.api.malformed_request_body"               
    }                                                               
  ],                                                                
  "messages": []                                                    
}
```

This works: `"(ip.src in {'$a'})"`.

Comment: try `"(ip.src in {'"$a $b"'})",`

Comment: @oguzismail this worked, why? It's the same (i thought) as `new filter="$a $b"`.

Comment: nah, not the same. you didn't quote `$new_filter` and it expanded to two words, `...'"$new_filter"'...` would work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, let's take your first example and modify it to print the JSON body:

```
export a=122.16.89.10
export b=137.77.77.77

echo '[
{
   "id": "ID",
   "paused": false,
   "expression": "(ip.src in {'$a'" "'$b'})",
   "description": "Block IP"
}
]'
```

The output is this:

```
{
   "id": "ID",
   "paused": false,
   "expression": "(ip.src in {122.16.89.10" "137.77.77.77})",
   "description": "Block IP"
}
]
```

You can see that JSON is not valid. The double quotes are unbalanced in `expression`.

Try `"expression": "(ip.src in {'$a' '$b'})",` instead -- that will produce valid JSON.

Comment: This will work for **this case** but not a good practice to use in general. If `$a` or `$b` should contain spaces word splitting issues will emerge again

Comment: @oguzismail it produces `"expression": "(ip.src in {122.16.89.10 137.77.77.77})"` -- the IPs don't need to be quoted inside of the filter string according to the doc. Spaces in `$a` and `$b` shouldn't break anything.

Comment: I was talking about leaving `$a` and `$b` unquoted, in this case; it's ok